# Jquery contextMenu plugin fails to accept default selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

Utilizing the example [here](http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu/demo/input.html)

```
 select: {
                name: "Select", 
                type: 'select', 
                options: {1: 'one', 2: 'two', 3: 'three'}, 
                selected: 2
            }
```

refuses to have the default selection of the drop down menu be `two` and instead leaves it as `one` .  We are using jQuery 1.8, is there a known issue with the above code on this version or is there some workaround that can be put in place?  The issue even persists on the demo page.

```
Environment:
jQuery 1.8
Firefox 19.0
```

working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JdwxT/175/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I checked the plugin, I think it never worked with `selected` value of the select, but it use the current value only a run time.

This is because the `setInputValues` function set the selected property if is it undefined in the `data` object.
I have fixed the code by setting the property only if the data object is not undefined.

See:

```
// import values into <input> commands
$.contextMenu.setInputValues = function(opt, data) {
    if (data === undefined) {
        data = {};
    }

    $.each(opt.inputs, function(key, item) {
        switch (item.type) {
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                item.value = data[key] || "";
                break;

            case 'checkbox':
                item.selected = data[key] ? true : false;
                break;

            case 'radio':
                item.selected = (data[item.radio] || "") == item.value ? true : false;
                break;

            case 'select':
                if (data[key]!=undefined ){
                  item.selected = data[key] || "";
                }
                break;
        }
    });
};
```

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vYnv3/1/

Here is a pastebin of the fixed code: http://pastebin.com/Mg3j7ifB

If works weel I'll fork the fix.

### EDIT

Added support for radio and checkbox too:

```
// import values into <input> commands
$.contextMenu.setInputValues = function(opt, data) {
    if (data === undefined) {
        data = {};
    }

    $.each(opt.inputs, function(key, item) {
        switch (item.type) {
            case 'text':
            case 'textarea':
                item.value = data[key] || "";
                break;

            case 'checkbox':
                if (data[key]!=undefined ){
                    item.selected = data[key] ? true : false;
                }
                break;

            case 'radio':
                if (data[item.radio]!=undefined ){
                    item.selected = (data[item.radio] || "") == item.value ? true : false;
                }
                break;

            case 'select':
                if (data[key]!=undefined ){
                  item.selected = data[key] || "";
                }
                break;
        }
    });
};
```

New pastebin: http://pastebin.com/c8XFVMiD

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vYnv3/2/

Comment: That does fix the selected issue on the select box, however it does not resolve the checkbox (boolean fields)